# How to split records per hour in order to display them as a chart?

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I have an SQL table like this : `sales(product,timestamp)`
I want to display a chart using Open Flash Chart but i don't know how to get the total sales per hour within the last 12 hours. ( the timestamp column is the sale date )

By example i will end up with an array like this : `array(12,5,8,6,10,35,7,23,4,5,2,16)` every number is the total sales in each hour.

Note: i want to use php or only mysql for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL is

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp), COUNT(product)
FROM sales
ORDER BY HOUR(timestamp)
```

Loop over the result to get it into an array.

EDIT: Applying requested where condition for unix timestamp

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp), COUNT(product)
FROM sales
WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR))
ORDER BY HOUR(timestamp)
```

Comment: I forgot, i want it to only get the latest 12 hours :D i think Keith's Date_sub doesn't work for me

Comment: Updated the answer, for future reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT HOUR(timestamp),COUNT(*)
FROM sales
WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
GROUP BY HOUR(timestamp)
```

Comment: The timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR) part doesn't work :( maybe because it's a Unix time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo code:

```
foreach timestamp
  use date('G',timestamp) to get hour
  increment array value using the hour as key
```

Something along those lines. Watch out for timezones.